# Plot a sparse matrix vs a list in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sparse-matrix

I have an output that looks like this:

```
 (1, 0) 5.15280812642e-42
 (2, 0) -6.31593498364e-35
 (3, 0) 4.1137215863e-33
 (4, 0) 4.11347362121e-33
 (5, 0) 1.15690910918e-33
 (6, 0) 2.14943418749e-33
  :   :
 (4498, 0)  4.16882551974e-30
 (4499, 0)  4.16882551974e-30
 (4500, 0)  4.16882551114e-30
 (4501, 0)  4.16882786295e-30
```

The case will be easy if I can convert the sparse matrix to a list that contains all the floating point numbers.  Therefore, I use

```
 output = [ output[i][0] for i in range(0,4502)]
 plt.plot(t,output)
```

where t is [0,1,2,3....4501]
But it does not work.Is it a better method to plot these datas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you produce a reproducible example of your data (code that generates it, that is?)

Comment: Are you using `scipy.sparse` or something else? If you're using `scipy.sparse`, what type of sparse matrix is it? (i.e. CSR, CSC, DOK, LIL, etc)  Most of the sparse matrix types would let you do `plot(sparse_array[:,0])` and get what you want.

Comment: I use sparse.csr_matrix to make a sparse matrix.

Comment: @GuangyueHe If you're using CSR, just do `plt.plot(data[:4500, 0].todense())`. CSR matrices allow efficient slicing of columns.  Are you sure a line plot is what you want, though?  It's basically going to be a line along 0 with a few points sticking up.  Perhaps a scatter plot of the non-zero values or a stem plot might make more sense?

Comment: I just figure it out. I use plt.plot(t,[x[i,0] for i in range(0,nsamples)])
plt.show

Answer (score 0):

Your output vector is too short, `len(output) == 4999`.   Matplotlib won't like that.  And I think it's a bad idea to use the same name `output` for both that sparse matrix and the result vector.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `t`, matplotlib plots against integer indices anyway:

`plt.plot( [ output[i][0] for i in range(0,4999)])`

or if you really meant to plot the whole thing:

`plt.plot([output[i][0] for i in range(len(output)))`

or more pythonically

`plt.plot([i[0] for i in output])`